# AppsFlyer integration not working in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, analytics, appsflyer, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I Have added AppsFlyer in my ios app by following this link

[link](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032066-iOS-SDK-Integration-Guide-v3-3-x-New-API-#iOS_SDK_Download)

and its showing following error

```
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerUtils in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerUtils.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerUtils.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppsFlyerUtils in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerUtils.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerUtils.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._appsFlyerDevKey in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._useReceiptValidationSandbox in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.userEmails in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerTracker in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppsFlyerTracker in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._backgroundTaskIdentifier in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.sessionConfiguration in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.sourceApplication in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.statSession in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.keychain in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.deeplink in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._isDebug in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._disableAppleAdSupportTracking in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._disableIAdTracking in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.dispatchQueue in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._delegate in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.emailCryptType in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.lastLaunchTime in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.platfromDevName in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._shouldCollectDeviceName in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._currencyCode in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._deviceTrackingDisabled in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.pushPayload in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.iADV3data in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._customData in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.didCollectIAdData in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker.referralURL in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._customerUserID in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerTracker._appleAppID in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerTracker.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerServerHandler in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerServerHandler.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerServerHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppsFlyerServerHandler in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerServerHandler.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerServerHandler.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCache.cachedRequests in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCache.cacheDirectoryPath in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCache.failedToInitialize in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerRequestCache in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppsFlyerRequestCache in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCache.isSendingCachedData in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCache.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.identifier in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.accessGroup in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerKeychainWrapper.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerDictionary in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerDictionary.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerDictionary.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppsFlyerDictionary in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerDictionary.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerDictionary.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerDictionary._dict in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerDictionary.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerDictionary.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCacheData._cacheKey in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCacheData._sdkVersion in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCacheData._postData in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppsFlyerRequestCacheData in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppsFlyerRequestCacheData in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppsFlyerRequestCacheData._requestURL in:
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/AppsFlyer.framework/AppsFlyer(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
    /Users/Company/Documents/iosApp/Company/libAppsFlyerLib.a(AppsFlyerRequestCacheData.o)
ld: 54 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

anyone have idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check please Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and remove duplicate in your target

Comment: there is no duplicate lib

Comment: Check Copy Bundle Resources and Compile Sources

Comment: the compiler errors says that you have a duplicate links to you AppsFlyer lib in your project. Try remove it from project and add again

Comment: tried twice using pod and static lib ...but always it saying same error

Comment: Solution is remove -ObjC  & $(inherit) flag from Other linker flags

Answer (score 0):

Check in your project navigator, you have imported same file twice or there is some cycle in `import` file.

Comment: cycle in import means?

Comment: You have imported same file in .h and .m both.

Comment: Check import files, may be you import .m file. And also check BuildPhases not contain any .h file.

Comment: Solution is remove -ObjC  & $(inherit) flag from Other linker flags